# Azure Batch Node Start Task fails

Tags: azure-batch

I am following MSFT docs and trying to set the following start task (copied from the official documentation): cmd /c "pip install azure-storage-blob pandas"

I keep receiving the error message that the task program is not found. I found a relevant post in which an accepted solution was to create a new pool programmatically, but I wonder if there is a way to make it work via UX as the documentaion suggests.

Any help or advice is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this post https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/install-python-on-a-windows-node-using-a-start-task-with-azure/ba-p/2341854